# angularjs base64 url parameters too long

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to find a decent solution to an issue I have.
Basically I have a set of questions that are answered across views. I would like it so that I can copy the url and paste it to another person and they will get the exact questions and answers I had.
I don't want to use lots and lots of query parameters, so I decided to base64 my questions object and then decode it on the fly which sounded like a good plan.

So I used bower to install **angular-base64** and created a simple **encode** method:

```
function encode(groups) {
    var simpleQuestions = groups.map(function (group) {
        var questions = group.questions.map(function (question) {
            return { id: question.id, answer: question.answer };
        })
        return { id: group.id, questions: questions };
    });
    return $base64.encode(angular.toJson(simpleQuestions));
};
```

This generates the string perfectly.
I then created a **decode** method:

```
function decode(data) {
    if (!data) return data;
    return angular.fromJson($base64.decode(data));
};
```

and an **applyAnswers** method:

```
function applyAnswers(groups, simpleGroups) {
    if (simpleGroups) {
        groups.forEach(function (group) {
            var simpleGroup = simpleGroups.find(function (item) {
                return item.id === group.id;
            });

            if (simpleGroup) {
                group.questions.forEach(function (question) {
                    var simpleQuestion = simpleGroup.questions.find(function (item) {
                        return item.id === question.id;
                    });

                    if (simpleQuestion) {
                        question.answer = simpleQuestion.answer;
                    }
                })
            }
        });
    }
    return true;
};
```

The problem with this, is the string generated is massive and when I refresh the page I get a bad request (presumably because the url is too long).
So, I decided that the best solution would be to encrypt the base64 string. So I downloaded **crypto-js** but when I try to use it I get an error stating:

> invalid array length

This is in the **WordArray.clamp** method.

So, my question is, what is the best way to create a string that isn't too long, but will have all the information I required?

Comment: So why base64 which expands the size of the data by roughly 30%

Comment: Do you want to store/transport free-form answers that the user typed in in text form this way, or what exactly?

Comment: Maybe it is better to save you json data using POST in the db and then you'll have only one parameter as id/uid?

Comment: I don't want to do that because the answers / questions change on every view and I don't want a POST/PUT on every transition.

Comment: @e4c5 I am asking what I can do instead. So if you have a suggestion I am open to it.

Comment: Why are you so worried about POST/PUT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this was not a problem with URLs being too long, it was a problem with the **ui-router** state parameters trying to be resolved as another state.
I did have my state set up like this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('widget.wizard')
        .config(wizardRoutes);

    wizardRoutes.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

    function wizardRoutes($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('category.two', configureTwoRoute());

        function configureTwoRoute() {
            return {
                url: '/two/:data',
                views: {
                    '': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/two/two.html',
                        controller: 'StepTwoController',
                        controllerAs: 'controller'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    decode: ['$stateParams', 'groups', 'questionProvider', function ($stateParams, groups, questionProvider) {
                        var simpleGroups = questionProvider.decode($stateParams.data);

                        return questionProvider.applyAnswers(groups, simpleGroups);
                    }],
                    score: ['wizardService', 'groups', 'products', 'decode', function (wizardService, groups, products) {
                        return wizardService.score(groups, products);
                    }]
                },
                data: {
                    requireLogin: true,
                    pageTitle: 'Step two'
                }
            };
        };
    };
})();
```

But it appears that was getting muddled with a child state.
I Changed the state declaration to this:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('widget.wizard')
        .config(wizardRoutes);

    wizardRoutes.$inject = ['$stateProvider'];

    function wizardRoutes($stateProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('category.two', configureTwoRoute());

        function configureTwoRoute() {
            return {
                url: '/two?g',
                views: {
                    '': {
                        templateUrl: 'app/two/two.html',
                        controller: 'StepTwoController',
                        controllerAs: 'controller'
                    }
                },
                resolve: {
                    decode: ['$stateParams', 'groups', 'questionProvider', function ($stateParams, groups, questionProvider) {
                        var simpleGroups = questionProvider.decode($stateParams.g);

                        return questionProvider.applyAnswers(groups, simpleGroups);
                    }],
                    score: ['wizardService', 'groups', 'products', 'decode', function (wizardService, groups, products) {
                        return wizardService.score(groups, products);
                    }]
                },
                data: {
                    requireLogin: true,
                    pageTitle: 'Step two'
                }
            };
        };
    };
})();
```

and it works fine now.